# NextJS API Route Returns Before Data Received?

Tags: async-await, next.js, settimeout, es6-promise, event-loop

I'm not sure what's going on here. I have set up an API route in NextJS that returns before the data has been loaded. Can anyone point out any error here please?

I have this function that calls the data from makeRequest():

```
export async function getVendors() {
  const vendors = await makeRequest(`Vendor.json`);
  console.log({ vendors });
  return vendors;
}
```

Then the route: /api/vendors.js

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const response = await getVendors();
  return res.json(response);
};
```

And this is the makeRequest function:

```
const makeRequest = async (url) => {
  // Get Auth Header
  const axiosConfig = await getHeader();

  // Intercept Rate Limited API Errors & Retry
  api.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
      await new Promise(function (res) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          res();
        }, 2000);
      });

      const originalRequest = error.config;

      if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        token[n] = null;
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const refreshedHeader = await getHeader();
        api.defaults.headers = refreshedHeader;
        originalRequest.headers = refreshedHeader;
        return Promise.resolve(api(originalRequest));
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  // Call paginated API and return number of requests needed.
  const getQueryCount = await api.get(url, axiosConfig).catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  });
  const totalItems = parseInt(getQueryCount.data['@attributes'].count);
  const queriesNeeded = Math.ceil(totalItems / 100);

  // Loop through paginated API and push data to dataToReturn
  const dataToReturn = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < queriesNeeded; i++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const res = await api.get(`${url}?offset=${i * 100}`, axiosConfig);
        console.log(`adding items ${i * 100} through ${(i + 1) * 100}`);
        const { data } = res;
        const arrayName = Object.keys(data)[1];
        const selectedData = await data[arrayName];
        selectedData.map((item) => {
          dataToReturn.push(item);
        });

        if (i + 1 === queriesNeeded) {
          console.log(dataToReturn);
          return dataToReturn;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }, 3000 * i);
  }
};
```

The issue that I'm having is that getVendors() is returned before makeRequest() has finished getting the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your issue stems from your use of `setTimeout`. You're trying to return the data from inside the `setTimeout` call, and this won't work for a few reasons. So in this answer, I'll go over why I think it's not working as well as a potential solution for you.

### setTimeout and the event loop

Take a look at this code snippet, what do you think will happen?

```js
console.log('start')
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'), 1000)
console.log('end')
```

When you use `setTimeout`, the inner code is pulled out of the current event loop to run later. That's why `end` is logged before the `timeout`.

So when you use `setTimeout` to return the data, the function has already ended before the code inside the timeout even starts.

If you're new to the event loop, here's a really great talk: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0

### returning inside setTimeout

However, there's another fundamental problem here. And it's that data returned inside of the `setTimeout` is the return value of the `setTimeout` function, not your parent function. Try running this, what do you think will happen?

```js
const foo = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 'foo timeout'
  }, 1000)
}

const bar = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 'bar timeout'
  }, 1000)
  return 'bar'
}

console.log(foo())
console.log(bar())
```

This is a result of a) the event loop mentioned above, and b) inside of the `setTimeout`, you're creating a new function with a new scope.

### The solution

If you really need the `setTimeout` at the end, use a Promise. With a Promise, you can use the `resolve` parameter to resolve the outer promise from within the setTimeout.

```js
const foo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 1000)
  })
}

const wrapper = async () => {
  const returnedValue = await foo()
  console.log(returnedValue)
}

wrapper()
```

#### Quick note

Since you're calling the `setTimeout` inside of an async function, you will likely want to move the setTimeout into it's own function. Otherwise, you are returning a nested promise.

```
// don't do this

const foo = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true))
}

// because then the result is a promise
const result = await foo()
const trueResult = await result()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Nick.

Comment: I was running into this too and your thorough explanation saved me. Thank you Nick!